# How to merge array of hashes based on hash value but not merge values instead override

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[
  { name: 'Pratha', email: 'c@f.com' },
  { name: 'John', email: 'j@g.com' },
  { name: 'Clark', email: 'x@z.com' },
]
```

And this is second group array of hashes:

```
[
  { name: 'AnotherNameSameEmail', email: 'c@f.com' },
  { name: 'JohnAnotherName', email: 'j@g.com' },
  { name: 'Mark', email: 'd@o.com' },
]
```

What I want is, merge these two arrays into one, merge based on `:email` and keep latest (or first) `:name`.

**Expected Result (latest name overrided):**

```
[
  { name: 'AnotherNameSameEmail', email: 'c@f.com' },
  { name: 'JohnAnotherName', email: 'j@g.com' },
  { name: 'Mark', email: 'd@o.com' },
  { name: 'Clark', email: 'x@z.com' },
]
```

**or (first name preserved)**

```
[
  { name: 'Pratha', email: 'c@f.com' },
  { name: 'John', email: 'j@g.com' },
  { name: 'Mark', email: 'd@o.com' },
  { name: 'Clark', email: 'x@z.com' },
]
```

So, basically, I want to group by `:email`, retain **one** `:name`, drop dupe emails.

The examples found on SO is creates an array of values for `:name`.

Ruby `2.6.3`

Comment: Your question is clear, but I would like to suggest an improvement. Notice that in my answer I repeated the two arrays in your example, assigning them to variables `a1` and `a2`. Had you assigned those arrays to variables I would have not needed to do that. (I could have said, "Let `a1` and `a2` be the two arrays of hashes...") but that is not convenient for readers who may wish to run my code. In general, when giving an example, it's helpful to assign all inputs to variables.

Comment: Thank you, Cary. I do as you said. Let's give some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could just call [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block on email key of the concatenation ([Array#+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-2B)) of the two arrays:

```
(ary1 + ary2).uniq { |h| h[:email] }
```

Comment: Good answer. I prefer it to mine. It depends on [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) keeping the first, but that is assured: "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept."

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a1 = [
  { name: 'Pratha', email: 'c@f.com' },
  { name: 'John', email: 'j@g.com' },
  { name: 'Clark', email: 'x@z.com' },
]

a2 = [
  { name: 'AnotherNameSameEmail', email: 'c@f.com' },
  { name: 'JohnAnotherName', email: 'j@g.com' },
  { name: 'Mark', email: 'd@o.com' },
]
```

Let's first keep the last:

```
(a1+a2).each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:email]=>g) }.values
  #=> [{:name=>"AnotherNameSameEmail", :email=>"c@f.com"},
  #    {:name=>"JohnAnotherName", :email=>"j@g.com"},
  #    {:name=>"Clark", :email=>"x@z.com"},
  #    {:name=>"Mark", :email=>"d@o.com"}]
```

To keep the first, do the same with `(a1+a2)` replaced with `(a2+a1)`, to obtain:

```
  #=> [{:name=>"Pratha", :email=>"c@f.com"},
  #    {:name=>"John", :email=>"j@g.com"},
  #    {:name=>"Mark", :email=>"d@o.com"},
  #    {:name=>"Clark", :email=>"x@z.com"}]
```